# Change syntax highlighting when doing ps-print-buffer-with-faces

Tags: syntax, highlighting

Hopefully a simple question.

I code in c++ in emacs with a dark background and the syntax highlighting is perfect for viewing that way, however when I print on white paper, some of the colours like yellow/orange don't show well against the light background.

I have tried doing M-x invert-faces default in the buffer and then printing, but this has no effect.

I am able to select the word, do M-x customize-face, and change the foreground colour this way, which works, but I don't want to do this when I'm printing. It's variable names that I want to change the colour of but only when printing.

What I would like to do it have a custom functions, which would temporarily change all variable names in that buffer to a different colour, print it, and then change them back.

The output of customize-buffer looks like:

```
Editing a setting changes only the text in this buffer.
To apply your changes, use the Save or Set buttons.
Saving a change normally works by editing your init file.
For details, see [Saving Customizations] in the [Emacs manual].


 Operate on all settings in this buffer that are not marked HIDDEN:
 [Set for current session] [Save for future sessions]
 [Undo edits] [Reset to saved] [Erase customizations]   [Exit]

Font Lock Variable Name Face:(sample) [Hide Face]
   [State]: SAVED and set.
   Font Lock mode face used to highlight variable names.
Groups: [Font Lock Faces]
Choice: [Value Menu]
 Attributes: [ ] Font Family: *
             [ ] Font Foundry: *
             [ ] Width: *
             [ ] Height: *
             [X] Weight: [Value Menu] light
             [ ] Slant: *
             [ ] Underline: *
             [ ] Overline: *
             [ ] Strike-through: *
             [ ] Box around text: *
             [ ] Inverse-video: *
             [X] Foreground: #FF8400    (sample)
             [ ] Background: *
             [ ] Stipple: *
             [ ] Inherit: *
```

Any thoughts on how to proceed?

Thanks

Joey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ps-extend-face` to tell ps-print to print using anther color.

> (ps-extend-face FACE-EXTENSION &optional MERGE-P ALIST-SYM)
>
> Extend face in ALIST-SYM.
>
> If optional MERGE-P is non-nil, extensions in FACE-EXTENSION list are
>   merged with face extensions in ALIST-SYM; otherwise, overrides.
>
> If optional ALIST-SYM is nil, `ps-print-face-extension-alist' is used;
>   otherwise, it should be an alist symbol.
>
> The elements of FACE-EXTENSION list have the form:
>
> (FACE-NAME FOREGROUND BACKGROUND EXTENSION...)
>
> FACE-NAME is a face name symbol.
>
> FOREGROUND and BACKGROUND may be nil or a string that denotes the
>   foreground and background colors respectively.
>
> EXTENSION is one of the following symbols:    bold      - use bold
>   font.    italic    - use italic font.    underline - put a line under
>   text.    strikeout - like underline, but the line is in middle of
>   text.    overline  - like underline, but the line is over the text.
>   shadow    - text will have a shadow.    box       - text will be
>   surrounded by a box.    outline   - print characters as hollow
>   outlines.
>
> If EXTENSION is any other symbol, it is ignored.

For example (from the file comments):

```
(ps-extend-face '(font-lock-keyword-face "RoyalBlue" nil bold) 'MERGE)
```

Comment: Brilliant ... works like a treat :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could try `M-x Customize`, then search for `Ps Use Face Background`, choose `Always use face background`.