# ps-print-buffer-with-faces with color-theme'ed dark background

Tags: syntax, highlighting, print

Similar to [Change syntax highlighting when doing ps-print-buffer-with-faces](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13401/change-syntax-highlighting-when-doing-ps-print-buffer-with-faces)

I typically use emacs with a dark background, but I'd like to print my buffer onto a white background (i.e. white paper). I use a color-theme, usually wombat, via `M-x customize-theme`.

When I call `ps-print-buffer-with-faces`, I end up with font faces suitable for a dark background, so a lot of the text is unreadable.

Honestly the solution posted in [Change syntax highlighting when doing ps-print-buffer-with-faces](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13401/change-syntax-highlighting-when-doing-ps-print-buffer-with-faces) is unintelligible to me; I only have a rudimentary understanding of elisp. Are there easier fixes? When I alter the color-theme to a light background temporarily, the output ps is unchanged.

Shouldn't there be an easier way for the printer output to preserve syntax highlighting while having colors suitable for a white background?

EDIT: it's all my fault. I had first used `C-u M-x ps-print-buffer-with-faces` to generate one file. Then as I switched themes and whatnot, I kept on using `M-x ps-print-buffer-with-faces`, which I thought was just overwriting the .ps file I had initially generated. I now realize you need `C-u` to prefix the print argument in order to generate a file instead of sending to the printer.